# Spring not returning 404 when saving associations that don't exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Working on a Spring Boot RESTful API application. It has a dynamic form building component, where my Event model can take arbitrary answers to a question. I want to be able to submit it all in a single POST. That works, unless the user gives an invalid question ID inside an answer JSON.

A `POST /events` looks like this:

```
{
  "eventTemplate": "http://localhost:8090/eventTemplates/1",
  "answers": [
    {"question": "http://localhost:8090/questions/1", "value": "Yes" },
  ],
  "location": "The Moon",
  "observer": "http://localhost:8090/users/1",
  "subject": "http://localhost:8090/users/1",
  "timestamp": "2018-03-19T13:26:44.108Z"
}
```

If I change "question" to http://localhost:8090/questions/17, which doesn't exist. I'd want a 404.  But I don't get that.  I get this:

```
{
  "cause": {
   "cause": {
  "cause": null,
  "message": null
},
"message": "N/A\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7751c231; line: 4, column: 18] (through reference chain: edu.harvard.h2ms.domain.core.Event[\"answers\"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->edu.harvard.h2ms.domain.core.Answer[\"question\"])"},
"message": "JSON parse error: null; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7751c231; line: 4, column: 18] (through reference chain: edu.harvard.h2ms.domain.core.Event[\"answers\"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->edu.harvard.h2ms.domain.core.Answer[\"question\"])"
}
```

Event entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Event {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "event")
    private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Answer entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Answer {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGEr, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
  private Question question;

}
```

The entire code base is at https://github.com/stbenjam/h2ms/tree/new-event-model.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The most specific thing you can do is to wrtie a custom exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    ...
}

@Controller
public class SomeController {
    @RequestMapping.....
    public void handleCall() {
        if (isFound()) {
            // whatever
        }
        else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(); 
        }
    }
}
```

There is of course other ways to do this: By using a `@ControllerAdvice` or a `return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)`. Just Google it, it is pretty documented.
Hope was helpful :)